# Function of getting being called but not showing in an angular test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have this code.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   ngOnInit() {
      // some code 
      this.method1(); // It comes up to here.
   }

   method1() {
       console.log('method1'); // It is not showing this.
       // Other method calls
   }
}
```

My spec file is:

```
  it('should call method1', fakeAsync(() => {
    const element = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    spyOn(comp, 'method1');


    fixture.detectChanges();
    // some code 
    fixture.detectChanges();


    fixture.whenStable().then(async() => {
       expect(comp.method1).toHaveBeenCalled();  // this works
    });
  }));
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you spy on a method you are replacing the original one with a fake one, that's why method1 is not being called

If you want to spy on a method without replacing it you must use callThrough:

`spyOn(comp, 'method').and.callThrough()`

Comment: Duh, I thought `spyOn` spies on the actual object method.